# Hive with Hbase integration null

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

everyone.I try use hbase integration but had a problem.the timestamp field query by hive is null.
my sql is:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_data(nid string, dillegaldate timestamp,
>   coffense string) STORED BY
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH
>   SERDEPROPERTIES(
>   "hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,0:DILLEGALTIMESTAMP,0:COFFENSE")
>   TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "ILLEGAL_DATA");

excute success,but query through hive

> select * from hbase_data limit 10;

the column dillegaldate is null,I googled for it a lot of time but still not find the problem.Can anyone tell me how to solve it?thank you very much

Comment: **(1)** show a data sample of `0:DILLEGALTIMESTAMP` **(2)** define `dillegaldate` as a string and show a data sample

Comment: the hbase data dillegaltimestamp is timestamp,like 2017-09-05 17:04:05.010     (2)the hive dillegaldate as string is like ?]?u3 ,totally wrong

Answer (score 2):

`0:DILLEGALTIMESTAMP` replace by `0:DILLEGALTIMESTAMP#b`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_data(nid string, dillegaldate timestamp, coffense string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES( "hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,0:DILLEGALTIMESTAMP#b,0:COFFENSE") TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "ILLEGAL_DATA");
```

a mapping entry must be either :key, :timestamp or of the form column-family-name:[column-name][#(binary|string) (the type specification that delimited by # was added in Hive 0.9.0, earlier versions interpreted everything as strings)
If no type specification is given the value from hbase.table.default.storage.type will be used
Any prefixes of the valid values are valid too (i.e. #b instead of #binary)
If you specify a column as binary the bytes in the corresponding HBase cells are expected to be of the form that HBase's Bytes class yields.

[HBaseIntegration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)